# Extracting control points from BezierFunction

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, splines

given a Bézier surface, is there a simple way to express $g_{12}$ (from the [First fundamental form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_fundamental_form#Further_notation)) again in Bézier form?

More precisely, I have control points and a Bézier function $f$:

```
cps = {{{0, 0}, {.5, .36}, {1, 0}},
{{.4, .37}, {.6, .3}, {.6, .42}},
{{0, 1}, {.45, .46}, {1, 1}}};
f = BezierFunction[cps];
```

I can compute $g_{12}$

```
g12 = D[f[u, v], u].D[f[u, v], v];
```

Since $g_{12}$ is a polynomial in $u$ and $v$, there is surely a way to express it as a Bézier function. Can I get the corresponding **control points** in some easy way from this representation? Or do I have to teach Mathematica what are the control points of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$, of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$, and what to do with them to get my result?

Thanks in advance for recommendations!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operation is surprisingly nontrivial, so I'm putting it out here for reference.

The idea is to work with explicit `BernsteinBasis[]` expansions and then do a few algebraic manipulations. To wit:

```
expr = Fold[Dot, #, {Table[BernsteinBasis[2, k, v], {k, 0, 2}],
                     Table[BernsteinBasis[2, k, u], {k, 0, 2}]}] & /@ 
       Transpose[cps, {2, 3, 1}]
```

yields the explicit basis expansion. Now, compute the required derivative:

```
dd = D[expr, u].D[expr, v] // Expand;
```

A look at the (long!) explicit expression reveals that the function does not yet have the compatible basis functions being combined. We thus need to do a few replacements:

```
ddn = Chop[dd //.
Times[a_., BernsteinBasis[n1_, k1_, u_], c_., BernsteinBasis[n2_, k2_, u_]] :> 
Times[a, c, Binomial[n1, k1], Binomial[n2, k2],
      BernsteinBasis[n1 + n2, k1 + k2, u]]/Binomial[n1 + n2, k1 + k2]];
```

Now, the (messy!) control point extraction:

```
ccp = (Function[b, Coefficient[#, b]] /@ Table[BernsteinBasis[3, k, v], {k, 0, 3}]) & /@
      (Coefficient[ddn, #] & /@ Table[BernsteinBasis[3, k, u], {k, 0, 3}])
   {{1.3328, 0.1648, 0.125867, -1.4048},
    {0.18, -0.122667, -0.0462222, 0.122667},
    {-0.357333, 0.249333, -0.0915556, 0.194667},
    {-2.0808, -0.250133, -0.1672, 2.1328}}
```

This can now be fed to `BezierFunction[]`:

```
nbf = BezierFunction[Map[List, ccp, {2}]];
```

Compare this with the usual derivative expression:

```
Plot3D[First[nbf[u, v]] - Derivative[1, 0][f][u, v].Derivative[0, 1][f][u, v],
       {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: difference]

and we see that the difference is on the order of roundoff.

Comment: It's been over two weeks and I am still flabbergasted that someone took the effort of thoroughly answering such an old question. Thank you! However, I cannot accept it before trying it out and that will take some time, as I don't possess any Mathematica license at the moment.

Comment: That is fine. ;) This seems to have been asked during one of my hiatuses, so I had missed it.

Comment: On Thursday I checked it on my friend's computer and it seems that you are right. Thanks again for the answer!